# Selectively Remove Auto Complete Entries from Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-8, autocomplete

I use Windows XP with IE 8.

When I try to access GMail (or any other site for that matter), the Auto Complete feature shows the list of username and on select of that, it auto-completes the password as well.

Is there a way, I can selectively remove one or two of the entries alone without having to delete all of Auto Complete entries?

PS: Ofcourse, I do know about In-Private browsing and that it can be used for ensuring that a History is not left behind and ...

Comment: 1) DL firefox/opera/chrome/lynx; 2) Start > Control Panel > Add or Remove Programs > IE8 > Remove. I kid.. :D

Comment: +1 for making a lighter comment! But, even with Firefox, how would I?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,1566838,00.asp

> When you start typing in a Web form with AutoComplete enabled, you will see a list of previous entries for the same field that begin with what you've typed so far. You can select one to avoid retyping it. To see all stored entries for a field, click in that field and press the Down Arrow key. To remove an entry that is erroneous, outdated, or private, highlight it using the Down Arrow (not the mouse) and press Del.

.

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080701095127AAQbra1

> In IE you can easily delete individual auto complete entries without using any extra software!!!
>   Here is how:
>   Open google.com,
>   then in the place the cursor search text-box, then pause for 2 or 3 seconds. Then click the mouse on the text box-again. When you do this, you can see ALL the auto complete entries, you had type before.
>   Once you see this list, hover the mouse (Remember! HOVER THE MOUSE! DON'T CLICK!) over the entry you would like to delete, and then press the 'delete' button on the keyboard. That's it! Repeat the procedure for all the entries that you would like to delete!

Below is for items you have typed into the url bar.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxxxxx\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs

Be careful what you delete in the Windows Registry

There is software that can give a little more control of what gets deleted, I am not endorsing this software, just posting it as an example

http://www.585soft.com/IEHistoryX.asp

> IE History eXpert gives you simplest and more safe way. Using IE History eXpert you can delete selectively only individual History links, Cookies, clear individual Temporary Internet Files, selectively delete IE Address Bar history items, delete only specific AutoComplete forms information and saved passwords.

.